# How does the water source affect the flavor of the sake?

Tags: flavor, sake, water

There are many different types of sake, each having own unique flavor profile and characteristics. Some [types of sake](https://www.sakesocial.com/blogs/guide/types-of-sake) are:

1. Junmai-shu: This is a type of sake made with only rice, water,
   yeast, and koji. It has no added alcohol or sugar, and tends to have
   a rich, full-bodied flavor.
2. Honjozo-shu: This type of sake is in a similar to
   junmai-shu, but with a small amount of distilled alcohol added to
   it. This gives it a lighter, smoother flavor.
3. Ginjo-shu: This is a premium type of sake made with highly polished
   rice, which gives it a more delicate, fruity flavor. It is fermented
   at lower temperatures than other types of sake, which helps to
   preserve its aroma and flavor.
4. Daiginjo-shu: This is the highest-quality type of sake, made with
   the most highly polished rice. It has a very delicate, complex
   flavor and aroma, and is often served chilled.
5. Nigori-shu: This is an unfiltered type of sake that has a cloudy
   appearance. It is sweeter and creamier than other types of sake, and
   is often served as a dessert sake.

The flavor and characteristics of each type can vary. How does the water source affect the flavor of the sake?

Comment: What is the reason for adding all of that context, to then simply make a statement "depending on factors such as ... the water source", and making that your question right after? Other than the title of your question, what you wrote, or copied from elsewhere (don't forget to attribute to prevent plagiarism if you did) Is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speculate, but natural sources of water have varying levels of dissolved minerals which could influence flavor.